# If we have a biased coin with the probability of tails equals $\frac{7}{10}$, is $\frac{5}{10}$ a better prediction than $\frac{9}{10}$?

Tags: probability

If we have a biased coin with the probability of getting tails equals $\frac{7}{10}$, is $\frac{5}{10}$ a better prediction than $\frac{9}{10}$? Intuitively it seems to me that $\frac{5}{10}$ should be better than $\frac{9}{10}$, but I am not sure why. So, I would like to understand answer for any legit probabilities instead of $\frac{7}{10}$, $\frac{5}{10}$ and $\frac{9}{10}$.

I am asking this because I've read [this blog post](http://bywayofcontradiction.com/even-odds/), and now I want to make a simple website where 2 persons can input their predictions of some event as probabilities, and it would give them the number how much everyone should bet so that it's fair, but I am not sure I like the author's definition of "fair".

Comment: How are we defining "better", what criteria should the better prediction satisfy?

Comment: I think it means if we flip it ten times, is it more likely that we get $5$ heads or $9$ heads?

Comment: We're more likely to get 9 times tails than 5, according to the bernoulli trials probability formula. It seems very unintuitive for me, even though now I understand why it is so, but I am still not sure if it means that 9/10 is actually better.

Comment: You probably need to better define what you mean by "better".

Answer (score 2):

Let's define precisely what one might mean by "better prediction."  Suppose we have a reference coin, whose probability of landing tails is exactly $p = 0.7$.  Further, imagine we employ a betting strategy which comprises the independent toss of a second "strategy" coin, whose probability of landing tails is $\theta$, for some $\theta \in [0,1]$ that we are free to choose, and that we "win" when the outcome of the tosses of both coins agree; i.e., both coins land heads, or both coins land tails.  We lose if the coins disagree.

The question that we are faced with, then, is "which of the two strategies, $\theta = 0.5$, or $\theta = 0.9$, produces a higher expected frequency of wins?"  This is an easy thing to answer:  If $X_1$ is the outcome of the reference coin and $X_2$ the outcome of the "strategy" coin, then clearly $X_1, X_2$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with $$X_1 \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p = 0.7), \\ X_2 \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p = \theta).$$  The desired expectation is equal to $$\begin{align*} \Pr[X_1 = X_2] &= \Pr[X_1 = 0 \mid X_2 = 0]\Pr[X_2 = 0] + \Pr[X_1 = 1 \mid X_2 = 1]\Pr[X_2 = 1] \\ &= \Pr[X_1 = 0]\Pr[X_2 = 0] + \Pr[X_1 = 1]\Pr[X_2 = 1] \\ &= (1-p)(1-\theta) + p\theta \\ &= 0.3(1-\theta) + 0.7 \theta \\ &= 0.3 + 0.4\theta. \end{align*}$$  It immediately follows that this probability is greater when $\theta = 0.9$ than when $\theta = 0.5$; therefore, the second strategy--equivalent choosing to bet on "tails" 9 times out of 10--yields a higher expected frequency of agreement with the reference coin than betting equally on heads versus tails.  In fact, we see that **always** selecting tails is the best strategy of all, with an expected proportion of agreement being $p = 0.7$.  And it may seem strange at first, but this even outperforms what we might initially think of as the proper strategy of selecting $\theta = 0.7$, which actually does **worse** than any $\theta > 0.7$.

A little more thought should reveal why this is intuitively true.